# How to know when all initial data is fetched from a root node using listeners in Realtime Firebase database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

**Goal:**

My goal here is to fetch initial data, update UI after I am sure all data is fetched, and continue observing changes immediately:

**The Problem**

I see two ways to do this:

1. To use `getData` method and to fetch all data at once (bulky). This is ok cause I know I have fetched all data at once, and I can accordingly update `UI` and continue listening for changes (`CRUD`).

The problem with this approach is that I can't just attach listener after, to listen to a for new additions (inserts), and wait for new items. It works differently (which makes sense cause I fetched data without being in sync with a database through listeners), and immediately after I attach the listener, I get its callback triggered as many times as how many items are currently in a root node. So I am getting most likely the same data.

So this seems like overkill.

2. Second way to do this, is just to attach the listener, and get all data. But the problem with this is that I don't know when all data is fetched, cause it comes sequentially, one item by another. Thus I can't update UI accordingly.

Here are some code examples:

I am currently fetching all previous data with a getData method, like this:

```
func getInitialData(completion: @escaping DataReadCompletionHandler){
        
        rootNodeReference.getData { optionalError, snapshot in
            if let error = optionalError {
                completion([])
                return
            }
            if let value = snapshot.value,
               let models = self.parseData(type: [MyModel].self, data: value) as? [MyModel]{
                
                completion([MyModel](models.values))
            }
        }
    }
```

As I said, with this, I am sure I have all previous data and I can set up my UI accordingly.

**After this, I am interested in only new updates (updates, deletions, inserts).**

And later I connect through listeners. Here is an example for a listener that listens when something new is added to a root node:

```
rootNodeReference.observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: {[weak self] snapshot in
            guard let `self` = self else {return}
            
            if let value = snapshot.value,
               let model = self.parseData(type: MyModel.self, data: value) as? MyModel{
                self.firebaseReadDelegate?.event(type: .childAdded, model: model)
            }
        })
```

This would be great if with this listener I would somehow be able to continue only updates when something new is added.

Though, I guess option 2. would be a better way to go, but how to know when I have got all data through listeners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this, but they both depend on the same guarantee that Firebase makes about the order in which events are fired.

**When you observe both `child` events and `value` events on the same path/query, the `value` event fires after all corresponding `child` events.**

Because if this guarantee, you can add an additional listener to `.value`

```
rootNodeReference.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
  ... the initial data is all loaded
})
```

Adding the second listener doesn't increase the amount of data that is read from the database, because Firebase deduplicates them behind the scenese.

---

You can also forego the `childAdded` listener and just use a single `observe(.value` as shown in the documentation on [reading a list by observing value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events):

```
rootNodeReference.observe(.value) { snapshot in
  for child in snapshot.children {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation. Both methods worked to fetch initial data. But, I am still getting same data twice for the first time. That is cause I first go with `observeSingleEvent(of .value)` which really gets initial data, but then I subscribe with `observe( .childAdded)` and then I get the same data (one by one, means call back is called many times). I thought this could be avoided somehow, rather than I have to deal with duplicates that I have received. Though, I didn't really understand deduplication part...

Comment: In the first solution in my answer you use the `observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value` merely to signal that the data is complete, so you can ignore the data in the `snapshot`. In the second solution in my answer you only have `rootNodeReference.observe(.value)` and no longer use `child` listeners, so you should also have the data only once,

Comment: I am sorry I am getting back to this. But I am still a bit confused, and I would appreciate if you could share one more thought about next:

Comment: So some suggestion here is that I can for example fetch initial data by observing a value with `rootNodeReference.observe(.value)` and then just continue using that for further changes (which is something I must continue doing immediately after) ? I am sorry I went into details, but my other concern is how to continue fetching data in optimal way. I was like: listening single events eg. `.childAdded` is more performant (after fetching initial data) rather than receiving all records at once by using `rootNodeReference.observe(.value)` just cause one record is added ...

Comment: "listening single events eg. .childAdded is more performant (after fetching initial data) rather than receiving all records at once by using rootNodeReference.observe(.value)" There is no difference in wire traffic between these two listener types. The client retrieves all data for a query/path or just the update, and then fires the relevant event(s) locally.